# Horizontal and vertical sortable divs

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-ui

I'd like to get an answer to my problem with a sortable grid. I'm having 2 rows with both containing 3 columns.

```
<div id="sortable" class="connectedSortable">
<div class="row">
    <div class="column">column</div>
    <div class="column">column</div>
    <div class="column">column</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="column">column</div>
    <div class="column">column</div>
    <div class="column">column</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I'd like these to be sortable vertically(the columns) and horizontally(the rows)
Here is my CSS:

```
    .row {  height: 200px;  }

    .row:nth-child(even) {  background: lightgray;  }

    #sortable {  height: 100px;  }

    .column {
        float: left;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 33.3%;
        height: 200px;
    }
    .column:nth-child(odd) {  background: red;  }

    .row:nth-child(2){
        background:yellow;
    }

    .row:nth-child(2) .column:nth-child(odd) {  background: pink;  }
```

Which looks like this:
[image]

I am unable to select the first or second row to change positions vertically, i think it's because of the columns that can be sortable too, and the colums are using full width of the row.

The only jQuery that I'm using is the following (with jQueryUI):

```
$(function () {
        $("#sortable, .row").sortable({
            connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
        }).disableSelection();
    });
```

Jsfiddle:
[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g4q95kp2/)

Answer (score 0):

I've kinda hacked my problem by using 'items' and a placeholder div. Somehow using a placeholderdiv makes me able to select the row block. Now I can select a row (by holding mouse close to the top of the row) and the first column.

```
    $("#sortable, .row").sortable({
            items: ".row, .column"
    });
```

See JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ort8zLmf/5/

But I would like to have a better solution.

Comment: Oh right, I misunderstood. My answer is meaningless then :P

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want. I have changed the layout so the columns all have the same parent and then used the below to clear them.

```
.conlumn:nth-child(3n) {
  content:"";
  clear:both;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/g4q95kp2/1/

Comment: Np, thanks for looking. But this is not what I wanted haha. I want to be able to sort the row vertically (be able to select the row and drag it up or down another row), and still be able to sort the columns horizontally.